# Negate exit status of process

Tags: exit-status

In a project, I have a test setup where I read the exit status `$?` of a command.

In my test, I want to ensure that the string `foobar` is not present in the output.

When I run the command:

```
./program | grep foobar
```

It returns `1`, indicating a failure.

I need it to return `0`.

Is there a way to negate the return value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` inverts the exit code of a pipeline.

```
! ./program | grep -q foobar
```